# In Scrum 2020: Who creates the Product goal?

Tags: scrum, product-management, product-owner

As by the Scrum Guide, The Product Owner is accountable for Developing and explicitly communicating the Product Goal.

The Scrum guide says, who develop the Product goal, bui I want to know who creates the Product goal, is it the Product Owner or the Stakeholder?

Thank you really for your answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Scrum Guide, the Product Owner is accountable for "effective Product Backlog management", and one aspect of Product Backlog management is "developing and explicitly communicating the Product Goal". Creating and developing the Product Goal are the same thing. However, the Product Owner doesn't have to do this alone. The Product Owner will have to work with outside stakeholders to make sure that the Product Goal is in alignment with their needs. The expression of the Product Goal must also be clear and understandable to both external stakeholders as well as other members of the Scrum Team.

Answer (score 0):

I like how this [scrum.org](https://www.scrum.org/resources/blog/product-goal) article puts it: Together.

> How do I create Product Goals? “In any way that works for you,” would
> be the consultant answer. There is no particular law or rule, but
> there are some things that we have seen working better than others.
>
> Set Product Goals together, leveraging the collective knowledge of the
> group but also as a first step towards acceptance and sharing of the
> goals. If you find this difficult to facilitate, have a look at
> liberating structures.
>
> ... https://www.scrum.org/resources/blog/product-goal